# ThinkPad Fan Control error

Tags: 12.04, thinkpad, fancontrol

I was able to install `tpfand` and `tpfan-admin` by following the instructions posted [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?s=b60757397b3098855bfeb02c867862e1&p=10112573&postcount=3). However, I'm unable to finish all the instructions.

After installing ThinkPad Fan Control I referred to the instructions again and did this:

> Now in the terminal again: Code:
>
> `sudo gedit /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/tpfand/settings.py`

A text file (gedit) opens up but the file is blank so I can't continue to the next step which is:

> Find the lines 170-174 and replace:
>
> ```
> Code:
>
> self.product_id = None
> self.product_name = None
> self.product_pretty_vendor = None
> self.product_pretty_name = None
> self.product_pretty_id = None
> ```

In addition, when I click on ThinkPad Fan Control this message appears despite being able to install tpfand:

[image: ThinkPad Fan Control error message]

Also, when I try `sudo thinkfan` I get this message:

```
WARNING: Using default temperature inputs in /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal.
WARNING: You have not provided any correction values for any sensor, and your fan will only start at 55 °C. This can be dangerous for your hard drive.
Config as read from /etc/thinkfan.conf:
Fan level   Low High
 0      0   55
 1      48  60
 2      50  61
 3      52  63
 4      56  65
 5      59  66
 7      63  32767
Daemon PID: 3367
juno@Oogushi:~$
```

I found this post on [how to control ThinkPad fan speed for T430](http://mastergenius.net/wordpress/2012/07/20/control-your-thinkpad-t430-fan-speed-in-ubuntu-12-04/), but I got confused on steps 6 and 7 so I aborted my experiment to do it.

Is there a way to solve this?  I hope someone can help me.

I'm using ThinkPad R61i 12.04 64-bit, Intel T5870 4GB RAM, 160 GB HDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this [link](http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_control_fan_speed) for detailed information on how to control thinkpad fan speed.There are some automated scripts which can help you to control the speed.

Due to slow fan speed your thinkpad might get overheated. This is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/751689). I found a very useful [shell script](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/751689/comments/9) to control the fan speed.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you for this, however I'm confused on how to follow the steps from the article since I'm not that knowledgeable in Ubuntu.

Comment: Check this [blog](http://blog.neolocus.com/2012/07/lenovo-thinkpad-x61-temperature-and-fan-control/) for the steps.

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask for clarification though? I've created _/etc/modprobe.d/thinkpad-acpi.conf_ and added `options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1` to a blank sheet of gedit file, saved it and closed the window. I'm not sure though what _Then reload the module_ means. Should I open the .conf file again or _/proc/acpi/ibm/fan_ and _/proc/acpi/ibm/fan_? I don't know what I should do with the code `># modprobe -r thinkpad-acpi
># modprobe thinkpad-acpi
 
Change the value of level
># echo level 7 > /proc/acpi/ibm/fan`

Comment: Once you set the fan_control to 1. You need to reload thinkpad-acpi module. So run `modprobe -r thinkpad-acpi`  `modprobe thinkpad-acpi` commands. After reloading set the fan speed to level 7 using `echo level 7 > /proc/acpi/ibm/fan`

Comment: This is result of running the first command: `juno@Oogushi:~$ modprobe -r thinkpad-acpi
FATAL: Error removing thinkpad_acpi (/lib/modules/3.2.0-29-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/thinkpad_acpi.ko): Operation not permitted
juno@Oogushi:~$`

Comment: You should run that command with root login.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4578/discussion-between-onvas-and-devav2)